# Snakemake output redirection and output managemnt

Tags: python-3.x, shell, snakemake

I am very new to Snakemake. Currently just learning using online tutorials. My problem is noted below. Any clue would be helpful.

- I have multiple files in input_data directory named as 'species1_multicopy_Ids.tsv', 'species2_multicopy_Ids.tsv' and so on. The file contents are very similar, where first column is just 'unique_id' and second col is 'protein_id'.

head species1_multicopy_Ids.tsv:

| uniq_id | protein_id |
| --- | --- |
| OG0002083 | XP_039695637.1, XP_039695638.1, XP_039695639.1, XP_039695640.1, XP_039695641.1 |
| OG0002085 | XP_039725676.1, XP_039725677.1, XP_039725678.1, XP_039725679.1, XP_039725680.1 |
| OG0002104 | XP_039734357.1, XP_039734358.1, XP_039734359.1, XP_039734360.1, XP_039734361.1 |
| OG0002113 | XP_039698803.1, XP_039698804.1, XP_039698806.1, XP_039698807.1, XP_039698808.1 |

- I wanted to write contents of protein_id column to text files, that will be named after corresponding uniq_id, for example, for `species1_multicopy_Ids.tsv` desired files would be `OG0002083.id`, `OG0002085.id`, and so on. `OG0002083.id` will contain `XP_039695637.1, XP_039695638.1, XP_039695639.1, XP_039695640.1, XP_039695641.1`.
- For this i have written a shell script that look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
    do 

        OG=$(echo $line | awk '{print $1}')
        content=$(echo "$line" | awk -F "\t" '{print $5}')
        echo "$content" | tr -d ' ' | tr ',' '\n' > "$OG.id"

    done < "$1"
```

- Now i want to process all the "*_multicopy_IDs.tsv" file with this shell script using snakemake.
- I have written a snakefile that works fine when used for just a single input file. I was unable to run it on others. My approach for a single input file:

```
def read_ids(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        return [line.split("\t")[0] for line in f if line.startswith("OG")]



rule all:
    input:
        expand("{OG}.id", OG=read_ids("species1_multicopy_IDs.tsv"))


rule extract_info:
    input:
        "species1_multicopy_IDs.tsv"
    output:
        "{specis}/{OG}.id"
    shell: "bash 00_scripts/myshellscript.sh {input}"
```

- I have tried to run the script with snakemake on multiple files without any luck. One effort look like this:

```
from snakemake.io import glob_wildcards


# Define the input and output directories
input_dir = "input_data"
output_dir = "out_dir"

# Get a list of input files
input_files = glob_wildcards(os.path.join(input_dir, "{species}_multicopy_IDs.tsv")).species

# Rule to create the output directory
rule all:
    input:
        dynamic(os.path.join(output_dir, "{species}", "OG{num}.id"))

# Rule to process each input file
rule process_file:
    input:
        os.path.join(input_dir, "{species}_multicopy_GeneIDs.tsv")
    output:
        dynamic("output_dir/{species}/OG{num}.id")
    shell:
        "bash 00_scripts/myshellscript.sh {input}"
```

- My desired output would be:

  - *.id files for each species in seperate directory marked by species name.

Many Thanks in advance!

Comment: Dynamic is deprecated and replaced with the checkpoints system.  There are loads of questions about it here and a this is a straight forward extension of the sample posted [here](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#data-dependent-conditional-execution) in the second example workflow.